# How do I remove duplicate datetime and also convert one column value into new column name?

Tags: sql

```
| datetime    | id     |name     | value   |
--------------------------------------------
| 2020-01-01  | 1      | foo     | 23      |
--------------------------------------------
| 2020-01-01  | 2      | foo     | 24      |
--------------------------------------------
| 2020-01-02  | 1      | foo     | 43      |
--------------------------------------------
| 2020-01-02  | 2      | foo     | 45      |
```

I need response something like.

```
datetime   |  1_foo   | 2_foo  |
--------------------------------
2020-01-01 | 23       | 24     |
--------------------------------
2020-01-02 | 43       | 45     |
```

What I have achieved till now is

```
| datetime    | 1_foo  |2_foo    |
----------------------------------
| 2020-01-01  | 23     | null    |
----------------------------------
| 2020-01-01  | null   | 24      |
----------------------------------
| 2020-01-02  | 43     | null    | 
----------------------------------
| 2020-01-02  | null   | 45      |
```

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic you want to implement.  (3) Show the query producing the results you are now getting.

Comment: Thanks for updating and also for correcting me. Great learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select datetime,
       max(case when id = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when id = 2 then value end) as value_2
from t
group by datetime;
```

I'm not sure what `name` has to do with the results.  You might also want `where name = 'foo'` in the query.

Comment: here name is nothing but you can take it as "column_name". I was not very specific with column name. Thank you for response